# How to know if the an account already exists when using Anchor's init_if_needed feature

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

Is there is an easy way to know if the account has just been created or already existed when using the `init_if_needed` feature?:

```
  #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        seeds = [seeds],
        payer = payer,
        space = 0,
        bump
    )]
    pub my_acc
```

Without  actually having to add fields  to the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way is to add fields to the account. By the time your program sees it, it'll just see an initialized account.

Depending on what you need, you could ask the anchor team to add an initialization hook, ie. additional code that's run after the account is initialized.